# How do i create a search link after user selects search criterias in webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have created a search.html where users can select/enter search criteria and click the search button to search the database of 1000 records. I have done the HTML part but I don't know how to generate the action link.

```
<form action="/bookings/search?" method="POST">
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Number of Tickets</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" name="numTickets" min=1 max=4
                value="">
        </div>
    </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
```

So, when the user enters the email or number of Tickets, the submit button will direct the result to /bookings/search javascript that goes through the database (Mongo DB). The email supports partial matching.
I want to do is: say, the user enters 'atom' in email and 2 in number of Tickets, then the action query should look like `/bookings/search?email=atom&numTickets=2`.

I believe it is related to javascript, but I am not sure how to do it.
My bookings/search looks like this:
[bookings/search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA34n.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed the method to "get" instead of "post" and it works.